# Translate MapKit Region Button Action to Method

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

Apologies in advance for what must surely be so simple.

I want my map to zoom to a programmatically defined region surrounding the user's location. I've found tons of code where this is done via a button action, but I need it done automatically when the map loads. I'll post what I've tried here. Probably missing something very obvious. The meat of these both work as button actions, so I assume my issue is with my method code (first line of each).

Method 1: Using MKCoordinateSpanMake

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    float spanX = 0.00725;
    float spanY = 0.00725;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

Method 2: Using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
MKUserLocation *userLocation = _mapView.userLocation;
    MKCoordinateRegion region =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (
                                        userLocation.location.coordinate, 3000, 3000);
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

As always, thanks so much for your time and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MKUserLocation *userLocation = _mapView.userLocation;
    MKCoordinateRegion region =[_mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (userLocation.location.coordinate, 3000, 3000)];
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: Hi @Nicolas, thanks for your response. This makes logical sense, but when I implement, I get a "redefinition of userLocation" error.

Comment: Thanks, removing the redefinition was the first thing I tried too, but still no luck.

Comment: The method is called ? if not move the code to, for example, `viewDidLoad`

Comment: That's what it was! Needed to move it to viewDidLoad. I knew it was something simple. Thank you for your help. I've added the original definition of userLocation back into your answer, so that I may mark it as the answer.